# For $w: \mathrm {C}^+ \to \mathrm{C}^+$, $w = \dfrac{az + b}{cz + d}$,$w'(0) = ad - bc$?

Tags: complex-analysis

So, for context, my textbook is trying to find a function $w: \mathrm {C}^+ \to \mathrm{C}^+, w = \dfrac{az + b}{cz + d}$ and it shows that its coefficients have to be real and finds out that $argw'(0) = 0$ and then it proceeds to say that $w'(0) = ad - bc > 0$. What I don't really understand is why the derivative is equal to $ad-bc$ and not $(ad-bc)/d^2$. I thought it might be an error but the book keeps saying the same afterwards. Where does that denominator disappear?

Comment: $w'(0) = (ad-bc)/d^2$ is correct.

Comment: See also the [Taylor series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+of+%5Cfrac+%7Baz%2Bb%7D%7Bcz%2Bd%7D+)